# react-pdf in nextjs is not letting to make build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-pdf, react-pdfrenderer

I am using react-pdf and react-pdf/renderer in nextjs after creating the file and adding the code it works perfectly but when I make the production build it continues to make the build and never stops.
here is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Page, Text, View, Document, StyleSheet } from '@react-pdf/renderer';


const PDFGenerator = () => {
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        page: {
            flexDirection: 'row',
            backgroundColor: '#E4E4E4'
        },
        section: {
            margin: 10,
            padding: 10,
            flexGrow: 1
        }
    });

    return (
        <Document>
            <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
                <View style={styles.section}>
                    <Text>Section #1</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.section}>

                    <Text>Section #2</Text>
                </View>
            </Page>
        </Document>
        
      );
}
 
export default PDFGenerator;
```

and here I am using it

```
                 <PDFDownloadLink
                    document={<PDFGenerator/>}
                    fileName="recipe.pdf"
                    className="button-background w-full text-center text-color py-2 px-4 
                     rounded mt-10">
                    {({blob, url, loading, error}) => (loading

                        ? 'Loading document...'
                        : 'Download PDF')}
                </PDFDownloadLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem, here is what I've done.

First some context:

- **Next.js** 12.3.1
- **React** 17.0.1
- **react-pdf/renderer** 3.1.9

Tried to prevent the page that uses the components from being taken into account during next.js compile time in two ways:

- By setting a state that becomes true in the componentDidMount lifecycle and conditionally rendering the component that uses the react-pdf/renderer library.
- By performing dynamic import of the component that uses the react-pdf/renderer library.
- Even a combination of both

In either case, running `yarn build` in the terminal does not complete the process.

> An important observation is that if I do not import the component that
> uses the library, the compilation does not take more than 30 seconds.

I've manage to find a "solution" or at least a possible workaround.

Like I said the project i'm working on is using next.js v 12.3.1. Apparently there is a bug in a dependency for that nexjs version.

The proper solution I think it would be to update your next.js version to the latest.

If that is not possible (like in my case) I found [this issue response](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/1802#issuecomment-1114654256) that gave me the idea and it worked.

In your next.config.js file, update the swcMinify to false

```
const nextConfig = {
  /* all your config */
  swcMinify: false,
}
```

Then you can go ahead and in your terminal run `yarn build` and you'll get your build done.
This was also discussed [here](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/2286).

Answer (score 1):

***TL;DR***  `npm add -D encoding` ***solved my case***

Hi, I've had a similar issue even with updated version of next.

• **Next.js** 13.4.4

• **React** 18.2.0

• **react-pdf/renderer** 3.1.11

During dev i was getting 'just' a warning (everything was working fine):

```
- warn ./node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'encoding' in \node_modules\node-fetch\lib'
de-ponyfill.js
./node_modules/@react-pdf/font/lib/index.cjs.js
./node_modules/@react-pdf/renderer/lib/react-pdf.cjs.js
./app/components/--which were using @react-pdf
```

silly me ignored the warning, and proceed to run build, than only met with:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/cross-fetch/dist/node-ponyfill.js
Module parse failed: Identifier 'Headers' has already been declared (20:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| const _fetch = fetch
| export { _fetch as fetch }
> export const Headers = Headers
| export const Request = Request
| export const Response = Response

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/cross-fetch/dist/node-ponyfill.js
./node_modules/@react-pdf/font/lib/index.cjs.js
./node_modules/@react-pdf/renderer/lib/react-pdf.cjs.js
./app/components/--which were using @react-pdf

> Build failed because of webpack errors
```

and the solution:

> In your next.config.js file, update the swcMinify to false
>
> const nextConfig = {   /* all your config */   swcMinify: false, }

didn't work for me, or any webpack configuration, or cross-fetch update or "downgrade", or --legacy-peer-deps with @react=pdf/renderer

but i've stumbled on this issue:
[Module not found: Can't resolve 'encoding' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/cross-fetch/node_modules/node-fetch/lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75748298/module-not-found-cant-resolve-encoding-in-vercel-path0-node-modules-cross)
where solution was to run:

> npm add -D encoding

and it work for my case with @react-pdf/renderer, i'm a freshie so i hope this helps

Comment: I will try this next time because I removed this package

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `react-pdf` is not supported by SSR?

Try using Dynamic imports and see if it solves your issue:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { PDFDownloadLink } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

// Lazily import when rendered on UI
const PDFGenerator = React.lazy(() => import('./PDFGenerator'));

const DownloadPDF = () => {
  const [showPDF, setShowPDF] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setShowPDF(true)}>Download PDF</button>
      {showPDF && (
        <React.Suspense fallback="Loading...">
          <PDFDownloadLink
            document={<PDFGenerator />}
            fileName="recipe.pdf"
            className="button-background w-full text-center text-color py-2 px-4 
            rounded mt-10"
          >
            {({ blob, url, loading, error }) =>
              loading ? 'Loading document...' : 'Download PDF'
            }
          </PDFDownloadLink>
        </React.Suspense>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default DownloadPDF;
```

Comment: sure let me check